# How to save a list of functions as an object in Python3

Tags: python

I'm working on a filter. For each case, I have a list of functions to process the input data, which differs from case to case.
I want to serialize and save such list of function, so that I can load and use functions for each case. I tried to use pickle to dump the list as a pkl file, but it cannot be load if I delete the definition of functions.
To deliver it more explicitly, it runs like this

```
def a1(obj):
    pass

def a2(obj):
    pass

def b1(obj):
    pass

def b2(obj):
    pass

a_func = [a1, a2]
b_func = [b1, b2]

if obj.flag == 1:
    for fun in a_func:
        fun(obj)
elif obj.flag == 2:
    for fun in b_func:
        fun(obj)
```

and I want to save such `a_func` and `b_func` as pkl file or so.
I don't know how to save them as py. I need to deal with more than 100 cases, and each case may need about 10 functions, most of which are in common. I don't want type them manually.

Comment: What do you mean by "I tried pickle, but it can not work as I expect"?

Comment: I think you want to save your functions as a module and import them from somewhere else. Simply save as .py file and import inside the code you want to use them.

Comment: Why do you think you need to `pickle` the functions? Why not just `from funcs import a_func`?

Answer (score 0):

Here you can try like this, using `exec()` and store string names of the functions in lists:

```
class obj:
  def __init__(self):
    self.flag = 1

def a1(obj):
    pass

def a2(obj):
    pass

def b1(obj):
    pass

def b2(obj):
    pass

a_func = ['a1', 'a2']
b_func = ['b1', 'b2']
objg = obj()

if objg.flag == 1:
    for fun in a_func:
        exec('{x}(objg)'.format(x=fun))
elif objg.flag == 2:
    for fun in b_func:
        exec('{x}(objg)'.format(x=fun))
```

Comment: Thank you Wasif, you inspired me. Maybe I can save functions in a single py, and define different augments for each case to call different functions

Comment: Yes, that maybe possible

Comment: I don't see any reason to do that... Why `exec` strings when you already have all the native objects? `exec('{x}(objg)'.format(x=fun))` here can just be `fun(objg)`... (which is basically the OP code...)

Answer (score 0):

You can define functions that use functions such as:

```
def a1(obj):
    result = obj+1
    return result

def a2(obj):
    result = obj*3
    return result

def a1_a2(obj):
   result1 = a1(obj)
   result2 = a2(result1)
   return result2
```

then calling `a1_a2` will do `a1` first and apply `a2` to the result of `a1`.
If you save the code to say `filters.py` you can do in any other programm in the same directory:

`from filters import a1_a2`

Comment: Thank you Dschoni, your answer also helped